# Measurability of a process defined by an integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, measurable-functions

Let $p(u,x):=(4 \pi u)^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4u}},u>0,x \in \mathbb{R}.$ Let $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+) \otimes \mathcal{F}$ the predictable $\sigma$-algebra. Let $u_0:\mathbb{R} \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{F}_0$-measurable and $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}E[(u_0(x))^2]<+\infty.$

**We want to prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(u,x-y)u_0(y,\omega)dy,u>0,x \in \mathbb{R},\omega \in \Omega$ is well-defined and $\mathcal{P} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable.**

While I was reading in a document, they proved for, fixed $u>0,x \in \mathbb{R},$ that $E\left[\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(u,x-y)u_0(y)dy\right|^2\right] \leq \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}E[(u_0(x))^2],$ can you make sense of $\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(u,x-y)u_0(y)dy$ using this inequality, in other words it's defined on an event $F_{u,x}$ such that $P(F_{u,x})=1$? Can you obtain an event $F$ independent of $u,x$? What about the $\mathcal{P} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bounded measurable $I \subset \mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R$, we have
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb \int_I \int_\mathbb R \mathbb E[p(u, x-y) \lvert u_0(y)\rvert]\ dy\ dx\ du\\
&\qquad \le  \sup_{y\in\mathbb R} \mathbb E[u_0(y)^2]^{1/2} \int_I \int_\mathbb R  p(u, x-y) \ dy\ dx\ du\\
&\qquad < \infty.
\end{align*}
From Fubini's theorem, we deduce that the integrals $$
v_0(u, x) = \int_\mathbb R p(u, x-y) u_0(y) \ dy
$$
are well-defined almost-everywhere on $I \times \Omega$, and $v_0\mid_I$ is $(\mathcal B(I) \otimes \mathcal F_0)$-measurable. By the continuity of $p$, we can further obtain that $v_0$ is well-defined everywhere on $I$ almost-surely.

As we can cover $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R$ with countably many such $I$, we thus have that $v_0$ is well-defined everywhere almost-surely, and is $(\mathcal B(\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R) \otimes \mathcal F_0)$-measurable, which implies the result.

Comment: In the last step, how did you obtain the measurability? How did you cover $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$? Can you consider $I_k=[0,k]\times ]-k,k[$?

Comment: By splitting into positive and negative parts, we can assume $u_0$ is non-negative. Then for your $I_k$, $v_0$ is the increasing limit of the $v_0\mid_{I_k}$. (The continuity argument might need e.g. $I_k = [k^{-1}, k] \times [-k, k]$, but the rest should work with your choice.)